# How to make DataGrid columns horizontalalignment stretch & customize column name - UWP DataGrid

Tags: c#, uwp

UWP DataGrid:[DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid)

**Q1:** I want to make the columns width divided equally and make it occupy all the available width, how is that?

xaml:

```
<controls:DataGrid x:Name="dt_Home" AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                           CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                           AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding UserSource, Mode=OneWay}"
                           IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

My DataGrid ItemSource is in my ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<User> UserSource { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<User>();
```

**Q2:** I want to modify the column names , for example, change the **FirstName** column to display **FIRST NAME**, how is that?

[image]

Comment: What did you try? Can you please provide a sample of your code as well?

Comment: Please share your XAML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q1: I want to make the columns width divided equally and make it occupy all the available width, how is that?

You could set Columns width with proportion, if you want make all columns occupy all the available. please set each width as `Width="*"`.

```
<controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn
        Width="*"
        Binding="{Binding Id}"
        Header="ID"
        Tag="Id"
        />
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn
        Width="*"
        Binding="{Binding Title}"
        Header="Title"
        Tag="Title"
        />
    <controls:DataGridComboBoxColumn
        Width="*"
        Binding="{Binding Link}"
        Header="Link"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind source}"
        Tag="Link"
        />
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn
        Width="*"
        Binding="{Binding Type}"
        Header="Type"
        Tag="Type"
        />
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn
        Width="*"
        Binding="{Binding Remark}"
        Header="Remark"
        Tag="Remark"
        />
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn
        Width="*"
        Binding="{Binding Time}"
        Header="Time"
        Tag="Time"
        />
</controls:DataGrid.Columns>
```

> Q2: I want to modify the column names , for example, change the FirstName column to display FIRST NAME, how is that?

`FirstName` will display with  `DataGridTextColumn` Header property, So you could edit FirstName to FIRST NAME like the follow.

```
<controls:DataGridTextColumn
    Width="*"
    Binding="{Binding FName}"
    Header="FIRST NAME"
    Tag="Time"
    />
```